# JXTaskPaneContainer grows wrongly when resizing window

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I have a [`JXTaskPaneContainer`](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTaskPaneContainer.html) on the right hand side of my JFrame which contains hyperlinks and labels. The window's main parts should be:

- a large area on the left for the text
- a smaller area on the right with the messages and the actions

Now, the problem is that adding a lot of new elements causes the container to grow to the left and over the text:

[image]

It gets even weirder when having the `JXTaskPaneContainer` inside a `javax.swing.JScrollPane` [(video/yt)](http://youtu.be/V4N8SIOcTEI).

The problem seems to lie with the JXLabel. 
I suspect it's the word wrap?
Any ideas how to fix this?

[Example]
Self-contained example as per request. [Full source on github.](https://github.com/jonnybest/layoutproblem/blob/master/src/layoutproblemSSCEC/SwingWindow.java)

```
package layoutproblemSSCEC;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXButton;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXLabel;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPane;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPaneContainer;

public class SwingWindow {

    private JFrame frame;
    String dolorem = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit "
            + "voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, "
            + "eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto "
            + "beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem "
            + "quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia "
            + "consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. "
            + "Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, "
            + "consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora "
            + "incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut "
            + "enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis "
            + "suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? "
            + "Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse "
            + "quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat "
            + "quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SwingWindow window = new SwingWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public SwingWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JXTaskPaneContainer panels = new JXTaskPaneContainer();
        JScrollPane scrollpanel = new JScrollPane(panels);

        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.add(new JTextArea(dolorem), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(scrollpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        content.add(new JXButton(new AbstractAction("Click me") {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JXTaskPane panel = new JXTaskPane("test");
                JXLabel lbl = new JXLabel(dolorem);
                lbl.setLineWrap(true);
                panel.add(lbl);
                panels.add(panel);
            }
        }), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panels.add(new JXTaskPane("Click the button, then resize"));
    }

}
```

Comment: check the layoutManager - taskPane (or container, forgot the details) needs a manager that respects prefSize. If that doesn't help, please post a SSCCE to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go trying GridBagLayout.

Comment: repeating: show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem - I'm pretty sure you'll get a concise answer ;-)

Comment: Done. :) See the full code after the link. That's as concise as I could manage. I think Maven will take care of the dependency (swingx-all-1.6.5-1) if you clone it in Eclipse.

Comment: no, that's not SSCCE: it's neither short nor standalone nor posted _here_ ;-) Shouldn't take more than 50 - 80 lines of code to reproduce a simple layout problem. Good to know your swingx version, though, so I can run your future SSCCE against the correct one.

Comment: Alright, posted the full 76 lines. The interesting bits are still near initialize().

Comment: cool- but now I'm really confused ;-) The example doesn't fit your description of your problem: where is the text to the _left_ of the taskpanes? and the taskpane isn't growing on resizing, just the contrary ...

Comment: You can't see the growing because the taskPane is already too big when the program starts up. Also I believe that both the unexpected growing and the shrinking are rooted in the same underlying issue. And I suspect it is the word wrapping JXLabel.

Comment: loosing patience (I trivially couldn't see the text in your first example because it wasn't there before your last edit ;-) And now the textArea isn't wrapping because you didn't configure it to do it ... And why are you focusing your question on the taskPane when you have a problem with the label?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me this far. I updated the code a final time. It now has a button. Click the button, then resize the window. You should see the problem exactly as advertised.

Comment: I tried, but I'm not able to influence the dimensions of the label in any way. Anyway, I care about the size of the taskPanel, which behaves odd if the label has lineWrap turned on. I'm quite lost here.

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was a concise answer to my question. I fear there is not.
I resolved the issue by creating a new layout, based on a [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) instead of `BorderLayout`.

There was also the issue of setting a minimum preferred size. Without calling `setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 127))`, the container's width seemed to shrink indefinitely, despite advertising a preferred width of 600. I'm still not sure where this comes from. The numbers are from the component's initial preferred size.

The [tutorial on oracle's site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) helped me here. The important part is finding weights which work. A weight value greater than 0 allows the component to grow and shrink.

This is what the layout code looks like now:

```
frmvanInput = new JFrame(); // window
// ... captions, titles, etc

frmvanInput.setContentPane(new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()));

// ... more initializing

/** 
 * LAYOUTS
 */
final Container contentPane = frmvanInput.getContentPane();

// the menu bar is on top, stretches all the way right
GridBagConstraints menuBarLayout = new GridBagConstraints();
// top left
menuBarLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START; // push to the top left
menuBarLayout.gridx = 0; 
menuBarLayout.gridy = 0;
// manage width
menuBarLayout.gridwidth = 2; // stretch
menuBarLayout.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // fill all x-space
menuBarLayout.weightx = 0.5; // a weight > 0 allows for resizing
//add
contentPane.add(menuBar, menuBarLayout);

// the text field is under the menu on the left and shares a row with the errors panel/scroll pane
GridBagConstraints textfieldLayout = new GridBagConstraints();
// top left
textfieldLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START; // push to the top left
textfieldLayout.gridx = 0; // col left
textfieldLayout.gridy = 1; // row center
// manage stretching
textfieldLayout.weightx = 0.5; // resizable
textfieldLayout.weighty = 0.5; // resizable
textfieldLayout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
// add
contentPane.add(txtEditor, textfieldLayout);

errorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(containerTaskPanel);
// prevent indefinate shrinking
errorScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 127));

GridBagConstraints scrollpanelLayout = new GridBagConstraints();
// middle, right
scrollpanelLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
scrollpanelLayout.gridx = 1; // right row
scrollpanelLayout.gridy = 1; // center column
// stretch to fill
scrollpanelLayout.weightx = 0.5; // resizable
scrollpanelLayout.weighty = 0.5; // resizable
scrollpanelLayout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
// add our controls to the visible world
contentPane.add(errorScrollPane, scrollpanelLayout);

// the emitter panel has the bottom row to itself
GridBagConstraints emitterpanelLayout = new GridBagConstraints();
// bottom left
emitterpanelLayout.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
emitterpanelLayout.gridx = 0; // col left
emitterpanelLayout.gridy = 2; // row bottom
// stretch width
emitterpanelLayout.weightx = 0.5;
emitterpanelLayout.gridwidth = 2;
// manage height:
emitterpanelLayout.weighty = 0.1;
emitterpanelLayout.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
// add
contentPane.add(emitterScrollPane, emitterpanelLayout);
```